# RxGo. How can I stop an observable stream?

Tags: go, rxgo

I'm just a beginner in learning the GO language.

I'm familiar with RxJava, RxJs, etc.

While studying rxgo, there is a part that I do not understand.

Why is 3 being printed even though an error has occurred?
Why didn't the StopOnError option apply?

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/reactivex/rxgo/v2"
)

func exam() { 
    observable := rxgo.Create([]rxgo.Producer{
        func(ctx context.Context, next chan<- rxgo.Item) {
            next <- rxgo.Of(1)
            next <- rxgo.Of(2)
            next <- rxgo.Error(errors.New("unknown"))
            next <- rxgo.Of(3)
        },
    }, rxgo.WithErrorStrategy(rxgo.StopOnError))

    for v := range observable.Observe() {
        fmt.Printf("CHECK %+v\n", v)
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
CHECK {V:1 E:<nil>}
CHECK {V:2 E:<nil>}
CHECK {V:<nil> E:unknown}
CHECK {V:3 E:<nil>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like library expects client to perform some transformation on Observable to trigger strategy. I tried `Map` but based on source code, it is embedded in other methods.

It is not very intuitive, and I did not find if that behavior is documented.

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/reactivex/rxgo/v2"
)

func main() {
    errs := rxgo.Just(
        rxgo.Of(1),
        errors.New("foo"),
        rxgo.Of(2),
        rxgo.Of(3),
    )()
    for v := range errs.Observe(rxgo.WithErrorStrategy(rxgo.StopOnError)) {
        fmt.Printf("CHECK %+v %v\n", v, v.Error())
    }

    errs = rxgo.Just(
        rxgo.Of(1),
        errors.New("foo"),
        rxgo.Of(2),
        rxgo.Of(3),
    )().Map(func(ctx context.Context, i interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return i, nil
    })
    for v := range errs.Observe(rxgo.WithErrorStrategy(rxgo.StopOnError)) {
        fmt.Printf("CHECK MAP %+v %v\n", v, v.Error())
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/n2Cr-p6pUC5

It is actually can be a bug in library. `rxgo.StopOnError` is a default strategy and there is an example for overriding it:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxGo/blob/6d27cca9572a67c6c423d4d4d41afd8edf5b1d72/doc/errors.md

Problem with that example that changing `rxgo.Continue` to `rxgo.StopOnError` does not change anything:

```golang
    errs := rxgo.Just(
        errors.New("foo"),
        errors.New("bar"),
        errors.New("baz"),
    )().Errors(rxgo.WithErrorStrategy(rxgo.StopOnError))
    fmt.Println(errs)
```

prints

```
[foo bar baz]
```

https://go.dev/play/p/swFwTo-q7c2

Comment: RxGo seems to be a stupid ReactiveX. I don't understand how RxGo is registered in ReactiveX's official repository. That's a disappointment for developers who love ReactiveX.

Comment: You always can submit PR with fix, report an issue or create your own fork. This is open source software that someone developed for free and shared with community. They deserve some respect for their work.

Comment: Yes, You are right.